# Setting item in combobox in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, linq, combobox

I have a fairly simple task to do, or so I thought. 
I have a combo-box in silverlight which holds some values like:

```
ComboBox hej = new ComboBox();
hej.Items.Add("blue");
hej.Items.Add("yellow");
hej.Items.Add("red");
hej.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

If a user then saves his work he can select a color, and it will be saved as a string in the database. 
When I come back as a user and load the page I want to see the color that I choose the last time.

So this is how I think I might solve the problem, but is there another easier way, I still get some errors with this:

```
object hit;

hit = hej.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => ((string)item).StartsWith(
    ivTestXml.StatusColour, 
    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

if (hit != null)
{
    hej.SelectedItem = hit;
}
```

Comment: Are you binding or adding non-string items into the `hej.Items` collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight (and WPF), the SelectedItem property doesn't expect a ListBoxItem object, but returns and accepts the value itself.  Try simply:

```
hej.SelectedItem = ivTestXml.StatusColour;
```

instead.  That said, you're not really doing this task the "Silverlight way".  I'm assuming you're from a Windows Forms or ASP.NET background.  Silverlight is designed to be worked with a little differently to those technologies.  You're better off performing this task using binding, where the view "pulls" the data to itself (generally from a view model, using the MVVM design pattern), rather than trying to "push" the data into the view from code-behind, as you appear to be doing.  It requires quite a mind shift, and will take a little while to break through that barrier.  But once you do, it'll make perfect sense.  You're best off having a view model that exposes an ObservableCollection property (for the list of items), and a string property for the selected item.  The combo box can then bind to these properties.

Hope this helps...

Chris Anderson